# HTTP REST Gateway to AMQP Request-Response, Without Web Sockets Or Polling

Tags: python, rest, flask, rabbitmq, amqp

I've struggled for two days to understand how REST API Gateways should return GET requests to browsers when the backend service runs on AMQP (without using Web Sockets or polling).

Have successfully RPC'ed betweeen AMQP service (with RabbitMqs reply_to & correlation_id), but with Flask HTTP request waiting I'm still lost.

**gateway.py - Response Handler Inside The HTTP Handler, Times out**

```
def products_get():
    def handler(ch=None, method=None, properties=None, body=None):
        if body:
            return body
        return False

    return_queue = 'products.get.return'
    broker.channel.queue_declare(return_queue)
    broker.channel.basic_consume(handler, return_queue)

    broker.publish(exchange='', routing_key='products.get', body='Request data', properties=pika.BasicProperties(reply_to=return_queue))

    now = time.time()         # for timeout.  Not having this returns 'no content' immediately
    while time.time() < now + 1:  
        if handler():
            return handler()
        return 'Time out'
```

POST/PUT can simply send the AMQP message, return 200/201/201 immediately and the service work at its own pace.  A separate REST interface just for GET requests seems implausible, but don't know the other options.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're asking is "how to perform asynchronous GET requests". and I reckon that the answer is - you can't. and should not. its bad practice or bad design. and it does not scale.

Why are you trying to get your GET response payload from AMQP?

- If the paylaod (the content of the response) can be pulled from some DB, just pull it from there. that's called a synchronous request.
- If the payload must be processed in some backend, send it away and don't have the requester wait for a response. You could assign some ID and have the requester ask again later (or collect some callback URL from the requester and have your backend POST the response once its ready - less common design).

EDIT:
so, given that you *have* to work with AMQP-backed backend, I would do something a little more elaborate: spawn a thread or a process in your front end that would constantly consume from AMQP and store the results locally or in some db. and serve GET results based on data that you stored locally. if the data isn't yet available, just return 404. ideally you'll need to re-shape your API: split it into "post" requests (that would trigger work at the backend) and "get" requests (that would return the results if they're available).

Comment: Hi @FuzzyAmi .  Am more after a synchronous GET request to an AMQP backend service.  This is because the backend service is written in AMQP where it accesses the database.  If it were written in REST I could, like you said, simply call it (albeit with service discovery).  Regards

Comment: @user2422819 - I've never seen a service like the one you have to work with here, and it makes little sense to me. AMQP (and rabbit) are not designed to be used in this way, although you could certainly abuse them to work if you wanted to. I'll add some notes to my answer.